# How to reduce the width of dropdown-menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 to create a simple drop-down menu, but I want to decrease its width and I can't figure it out how to do this.

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    width: 60px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.dropdown-menu` has `min-width: 160px;` and `min-width` overrides `width` so you can not change `width` you can use `min-width` instead of `width`.

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 60px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It works. You should call `bootstrap lib` and `jquery`. Please, read [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn).

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/rL1bdwL8/)

Comment: @PavelValeriu Let me check.

Comment: @Pavel Valeriu use `min-width:60px`

Answer (score 0):

Give a ID for the **div** and specify the **min-width** in the **css** as follows:

```
.dropdown #mydiv{ min-width:60px; }
```

Note: Do NOT use '!important'.
For more information check out this great post by Chris Coyier : [Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)